# initialize object with input

Tags: python-3.x, class

When I create an object I want it to have a list. I want to print out a sentence and after that ask for input which is necessary to fill out the list. But it first asks for input and then prints out the sentence. How do I fix this?

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2 ,num3):
        print("enter 3 numbers")
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
        self.num3 = num3

test_object = Test(input("num1: "), input("num2: "), input("num3: "))

# What I get:
#  >>> num1: 1
#  >>> num2: 2
#  >>> num3: 3
#  >>> enter 3 numbers

#What I want:
#  >>> enter 3 numbers
#  >>> num1: 1
#  >>> num2: 2
#  >>> num3: 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you take the input to the class so it calls the input after print before setting the class method.
With this, you `__init__`  will not have any argument.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        print("enter 3 numbers")
        self.num1 = input("num 1: ")
        self.num2 = input("num 2: ")
        self.num3 = input("num 3: ")
test_object = Test()

#What you will get this any time you call Test()
#  >>> enter 3 numbers
#  >>> num1: 1
#  >>> num2: 2
#  >>> num3: 3
```

### Or

Call the print statement before the class declaration

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2 ,num3):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
        self.num3 = num3
print("enter 3 numbers")
test_object = Test(input("num1: "), input("num2: "), input("num3: "))

#What you will get
#  >>> enter 3 numbers
#  >>> num1: 1
#  >>> num2: 2
#  >>> num3: 3
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I need the program to print that sentence and ask for input every time an object of that class is created. so getting the input into the class or more specifically into the __init__ method would work. But it doesn't seem very clean to me. is there no other more clean way to do it? Thinking of some sort of decorator maybe